Capacitance, Rate of charge flow

In the given circuit how would the charge on capacitor vary with time if switch is closed at $t=0$. I know it will increase with time but what will be the exact function. My book says it will be $CE(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}) $ where $C$ denotes the equivalent capacitance.

Can you use differential equations?

First, please use MathJax to typeset your formulas. Second, your book already gives you the answer - what is your question then?

I wanted to know how that answer came

Charging a capacitor

The answer can be easily arrived on by applying Thévenin's theorem, refer Thévenin's theorem.

If you need a very basic approach, here it is:
Let the amount of charge on the capacitors at any time $t$ be $q$. Since the capacitors are connected in series the amount of charge on both the capacitors at a particular time will be equal.
Let the current $i$ flow through the circuit at time $t$.
Applying Kirchoff's Voltage law:
$$\epsilon - iR = \frac q{C_1} +\frac q{C_2}\tag{1}$$
Let $C=C_{eq}$ be the equivalent capacitance of the system.
We know,
$$\frac 1{C_{eq}} =  \frac 1{C_1} +  \frac 1{C_2}=\frac 1C$$
applying in $(1)$ gives:
$$\epsilon - iR = \frac q{C}$$
$i=\frac {dq}{dt}$
$$\epsilon-R\frac{dq}{dt}=\frac qC \implies \frac{dq}{dt} + \frac q{RC} = \frac{\epsilon}{R}$$
This is a first order linear differential equation with integrating factor(IF)$$=e^{\int\frac 1{RC}.dt}=e^{\frac t{RC}}$$
this gives:
$$qe^{\frac t{RC}}=\int e^{\frac t{RC}}\frac{\epsilon}{R}\implies qe^{\frac t{RC}}=C\epsilon e^{\frac t{RC}}+K$$ where $K$ is the constant of integration.
At time $t=0$, $q=0 \implies K=-C\epsilon$
$$\implies q=C\epsilon\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\right)$$
$RC$ is also known as time constant($\tau$)
$$\implies q=C\epsilon\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\right)$$

The differential equation can also be solved by other methods whatever strikes first can be used
